# Auto launch the video player in Android from the browser like an iPhone does

Tags: iphone, android, video, mp4, x264

I have just created and iPhone web app, which has some x264 (mp4) video files on it. When I link directly to the file on the iPhone and the user taps the link, the video player is loaded and the video starts playing.

Using the app on an Android phone causes the browser to download the video instead of just playing it. Is there a way to force a video player to just boot up and play the video not download it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a sample link you can share that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: also, what MIME type does the server return the video file as?

Comment: Sample of the problem can be found here (open in webkit) http://magicseaweed.com/md/blacklabel/3/event/2/video/

Answer (score 3):

You should know that Android is quite strict regarding the video streams that you can stream. To be able to watch a stream a video (progressively watch and download) the video container must be correctly formatted.

There are many ways to create a container suitable for progressive streaming. You can look it up here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/2a801ce5f71b5aaf?pli=1

I have successfully created a streamable video. Try to open it from your browser: http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~nh209484/Video000.3gp

Comment: thanks for your tips i was trying to avoid recoding everything though :)