# Play media (video) from a network stream(http) directly

Tags: java, android, http, media-player, fileoutputstream

I would like play media (video) from a network stream(http) directly, hence so I have to somehow feed Android MediaPlayer with the data.

I have FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile); which I write into the outputfile by outstream.write(buffer, 0, count);

Is there any API which takes stream as input....???.... Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android supports Progressive download and HTTP Live Streaming(only in 3.0) and both of these work over HTTP.

You can use `VideoView` or `Mediaplayer` to leverage Progressive downloading and play your videos: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058945/using-videoview-for-streaming-or-progressive-download-video) discussion.

Also, if your server, delivers segmented files(.ts) in conformance to [Apple's Http Live Streaming IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-01), you can directly supply the URL to `MediaPlayer` and play your video using `SurfaceView`. Note: that you will have to replace "http" with "httplive:" in your URL.

Comment: For now my server is Youtube. And I see mediaplayer accepting audio inputstreams. But, in the case of a video stream What can be done ??

Comment: Try passing the URL directly to VideoView or Mediaplayer and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah....that is what I am trying now, but the permission of the file is getting changed when we give it for download. Will let you know the result...

Comment: Another issue in MediaPlayer.... I have implemented OnBufferingUpdateListener, but the MediaPlayer is not calling onBufferingUpdate. I have given mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);....But still it is not getting updated.... Any idea !!