# Video not playing in Android

Tags: android, media-player, mediacontroller

Video not working properly in the below mentioned code. What could be the problem for this?

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getBaseContext());
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoweb);

Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/v/wwI2w2YHkCQ?fs=1");
videoweb.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoweb.setVideoURI(video);
videoweb.start();
```

Error:

> Cannot play video 
>   Sorry,this video cannot be played.

Comment: Can you post the logcat messages?

Comment: @Ravi-error is-01-05 11:21:30.290: E/libEGL(2214): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread) Warning-01-05 11:21:31.020: W/webcore(2214): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

Comment: Non of the answers working for you? if you are still facing the problem, update us on what is the current issue you are facing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you have provided, `http://www.youtube.com/v/wwI2w2YHkCQ?fs=1`, is for an HTML page. The URI to be provided for `setVideoURI()` should be a media file such as [MP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) or [AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave).

VideoView cannot parse a HTML page. It can only decode and play a video file or stream a video content (in this case the URI should point to the media file, such as `http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/mp4/cavity_flow_movie.mp4`). See Stack Overflow question *[Using VideoView for streaming or progressive-download video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058945/using-videoview-for-streaming-or-progressive-download-video)*.

You should use a Webview for opening the YouTube link.

Comment: @Karthik-Yes you are right.. but i tried to use webview and loaded this url using loadurl function but nothing is displaying... any soln?

Comment: Do you get any warnings or errors in Logcat? check internet access permission etc.

Comment: @Karthik-I have given `INTERNET` permission in manifest and error is-01-05 11:21:30.290: E/libEGL(2214): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
Warning-01-05 11:21:31.020: W/webcore(2214): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

Comment: What context are you passing while creating webview? Try using `this`. `getBaseContext()` will not be suitable here as only `this` (instance of `activity`) will have the view details.

Answer (score 2):

`VideoView` and `Mediaplayer` can play only formats given in the document *[Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)*.

The link of the YouTube video you gave is for an *HTML page*. If you are playing an HTML page as mentioned by Karthik, it is better to use `Webview`.

```
String url = "your_youtube_link";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
```

If you want only the video to be viewed from that link, leave all other details in the page. Suppose this is the YouTube link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC7ZOGpM2cU&feature=g-logo&context=G233b464FOAAAAAAABAA

If you parse the source of the YouTube HTML page, you may see this portion:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DZC7ZOGpM2cU&amp;format=json" title="Bigg Boss 5: Juhi Parmar wins Big Boss season 5">
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DZC7ZOGpM2cU&amp;format=xml" title="Bigg Boss 5: Juhi Parmar wins Big Boss season 5">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="87741124305">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC7ZOGpM2cU">
<meta property="og:title" content="Bigg Boss 5: Juhi Parmar wins Big Boss season 5">
<meta property="og:description" content="Ntv News: Juhi Parmar wins Bigg Boss 5 - Juhi Parmar wins &#39;Bigg Boss 5&#39;, takes home Rs.1 crore - No kid for now, keen for good work: Juhi Parmar">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/ZC7ZOGpM2cU/hqdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZC7ZOGpM2cU?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="396">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="297">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
```

In this, extract the following

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZC7ZOGpM2cU?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
```

In this, the `<http://www.youtube.com/v/ZC7ZOGpM2cU?version=3&amp;autohide=1>` link will show it fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in order to play any streaming video I am using

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/v/wwI2w2YHkCQ?fs=1")));
```

But I don't think this is going to work for your link. Better to try

```
mediaplayer.setdataSource("your link").
```

Comment: @RanjitMishra-Do I need to use a VideoView to play the MediaPlayer?

Comment: U can either use VideoView or Mediaplayer.For mediaplayer,there is no UI component.You have to give if u want

Comment: yes,my dear. As exactly said by sonu thomas, MediaPlayer don't have UI, So either you have to create your own UI for mediaplayer to run video or Better to use VideoView directly.

Comment: @RanjitMishra-Neither VideoView nor Mediaplayer is helping me.

Comment: @sonu thomas-Neither VideoView nor Mediaplayer is helping me.

Comment: Better i think to play youtube in android is Webview,as @Karthik mentioned.Becoz it is not streaming link for mp4,etc,it is an html file

Comment: I have added an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

OK, try the following code. It will work.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/v/wwI2w2YHkCQ?fs=1"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    }

    private void playVideo() {
        try {
            final String path = "http://www.youtube.com/v/wwI2w2YHkCQ?fs=1"

            System.out.println("path  "+path);
            Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
            if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemo.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("else  ");
                // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
                if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                    System.out.println("mVideoView.start()  ");

                    mVideoView.start();
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                current = path;
                //mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
                mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    }
```

#### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/path"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/play"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pause"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/pause"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/reset"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/reset"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/stop"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/stop"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```