# video is not playing in samsung galaxy nexus 4.0.2 ICS 

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In my app I need to play video that is coming from a server.

The video is playing perfectly in all devices which are running 2.x and 3.x. However, on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.0.2) I get the error:

> Cannot play video. Sorry this video cannot be played

**Note:** I have given the application Internet permissions in the application manifest.

Can anyone tell me why I am only getting this error on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.0.2.

A URL to my server video can be found [here](http://myapp.com/loadvideo/fc8f920fd406d270846ac129d87ba803/4f28c042/mobile-videos/1cfe0e94b99cf4b0d84a5ef8049c188a_larry.flv.hq.mp4)

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725818/video-not-playing-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue that I didn't have on Android 2.x and 3.x.

I just added the following permission to the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```