# How do I display a YouTube playlist webview?

Tags: android, webview, rss, youtube

I want display a YouTube video playlist in a webview in my application. When it loads, it displays on the entire screen of my phone instead of within the layout of my application, which includes a tabhost with three tabs, a title bar, and a status bar. Other links display fine. How do I load YouTube without it taking over my screen?

These are the setting of my webview...

```
newsfeed = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewnews);
//Enables JavaScript (YouTube)
newsfeed.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
newsfeed.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Here is the line of code in question...

```
} else
    if(selectednewsfeed.contentEquals("4")){
        try{
            //This link display on entire screen
            newsfeed.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3PTjOdMKwY&list=UUBIwq18tUFrujiPd3HLPaGw&feature=plcp"); 

            //This link displays within the layout of my application, but as 
            //title and headline followed by source code
            //newsfeed.loadUrl("http://feeds2.feedburner.com/Maxkeisercom"); 
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

I also want to know how to display content from [FeedBurner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FeedBurner) in a webview. I want users to be able to read this feed and then access the podcast. How do I make a webview display full HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added this as an answer in [Video not playing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725818/video-not-playing-in-android/8804432#8804432).

I hope this may help you in a YouTube video to only fill your screen. `VideoView` and `Mediaplayer` can play only formats given in their documents named [supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

The YouTube link you gave is for an *HTML page*.

```
String url = "your_youtube_link";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
```

If you want only the video to be viewed from that link, leave all other details in the page. Suppose this is the YouTube link, `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC7ZOGpM2cU&feature=g-logo&context=G233b464FOAAAAAAABAA`.

If you parse the source of the YouTube HTML page, you may see this portion:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DZC7ZOGpM2cU&amp;format=json" title="Bigg Boss 5: Juhi Parmar wins Big Boss season 5">
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DZC7ZOGpM2cU&amp;format=xml" title="Bigg Boss 5: Juhi Parmar wins Big Boss season 5">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="87741124305">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC7ZOGpM2cU">
<meta property="og:title" content="Bigg Boss 5: Juhi Parmar wins Big Boss season 5">
<meta property="og:description" content="Ntv News: Juhi Parmar wins Bigg Boss 5 - Juhi Parmar wins &#39;Bigg Boss 5&#39;, takes home Rs.1 crore - No kid for now, keen for good work: Juhi Parmar">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/ZC7ZOGpM2cU/hqdefault.jpg">
  <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZC7ZOGpM2cU?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="396">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="297">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
```

In this, extract the following.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZC7ZOGpM2cU?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
```

In this, the `http://www.youtube.com/v/ZC7ZOGpM2cU?version=3&amp;autohide=1` link will show it fullscreen.

Similarly, you must extract the part of HTML codes for playlist.

I hope this may help you.