# Android: get stored video from database

Tags: android, database, blob, inputstream, android-videoview

I've prepared sqlite database in SQLite Manager with all data added manually. This db stored images (BLOB), text and video (BLOB) files. I cannot store only URL/SD card link to videos but whole file in database.
I easily can get text and images from database and show in my application.

For images code below:

```
Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getData(); // select from database text, images(BLOB) and videos(BLOB).  

...
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(1));  //image
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);  
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);  
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

And it is working.
But I don't know how to get video from BLOB and display/play in VideoView field using:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(2));  //video
```

How to put inputStream to VideoView or other format to display in application.
Please help.

**EDIT:** I stored whole database (with text,images and videos) on device. 
I connect with external database (MySQL) only for update. And after updating records i.e. with movies, device doesn't use Internet connection any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go Tom, you just want to do streaming:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059259/413127

Comment: Thanks for reply.
It is streaming video from external source tutorial. I want to get video from database (from field BLOB, NOT in some folder of SD Card) located on device (smartphone) and play in application.

Comment: Once you changed it into an InputStream it's irrelevant where you got it from.