# Android streaming video from camera

Tags: android, video, stream, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using VideoView for streaming or progressive-download video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058945/using-videoview-for-streaming-or-progressive-download-video)

I'm working on one App for Android and my purpose is to stream video over the phone camera to other Android phone (application). I don´t know so much about streaming video, and what I want to know is what I need to do?

I need to create a streaming server that receives the video from one android phone? How I do this?
And what is the best way to do this? How I can set up/configure a streaming server?

Can someone help me with some explanation or tutorials?

Comment: what's the original?