# Live streaming to android using 4.1 HTML 5

Tags: android, html, streaming, video-streaming, live

As most you of are probably aware flash will not be supported in the new versions of android 4.1 or above.

I am looking for a way to stream live video content to the new versions of android (I current just use flash) through the web browser.

I have tried html5 video tag and HLS stream however I have only managed to get the audio to come through.

I am testing this all on the android emulator.

At the moment there is no way for us to deliver content to anyone that will be using android 4.1.. Which is slightly worrying as it gains more users.

Comment: im not sure but have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058945/using-videoview-for-streaming-or-progressive-download-video

Answer (score 0):

IF you can use VideoView....

I'm using HTTP Live Stream for Android 4.0.3 right now with Wowza Media Server.

```
    private VideoView mainVideo;
    public static String VIDEO_FEED_URL = http://192.168.1.102:1935/http/myStream/playlist.m3u8

    mainVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.mainVideo);
    mainVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(VIDEO_FEED_URL));
    mainVideo.requestFocus();
    mainVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mainVideo.start();
        }
    });
```

Here's the tutorial I followed for Wowza.  http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-RTMP-based-encoder

I'm waiting for my 4.1 tablet right now to see if this works.  Unless Google changed VideoView, this should still work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer however I am looking to impanelment it through html5 as i want to be able to embed it onto websites. Just having an app is not really a solution as I do one off live streaming events the customer is always changing, meaning I would have to create an app for every event and is not worth it at the moment as the percentage of andriod 4 users watching live streams is very very small.

Answer (score 0):

On my Nexus 7 (Android 4.1) HLS / H.264 live streaming does *not* work in-browser.

However, if instead I supply or redirect to a link to the streaming manifest, this will launch the video player app, and that works just fine.

So a bit more JQuery hackery to wrap around something like JWPlayer or it's ilk

Comment: piers, i am facing same problem, now are you able to play hls in browser (html5) in Android 4.1? if yes, please help me to do same.

Comment: No. As best I can tell, that is not supported in Chrome Mobile. Hackery I mention above is to do a browser redirect to the HLS uri so it launches video player app